# jQuery & image slider/zoom effect

Tags: jquery, image, zooming, image-rotation, pan

I wanna to ask is there a plugin that can do a image slider/rotator and at the sametime it has the effect of the image zooming in?

Just like a normal slider, a container that hold image and description. Then it will show the image in certain interval, but the effect of image slowly zoom from far to near when the image appear/fade in.

for example like this video (link below), you see the video is zoom from far to near, is JavaScript possible to do that to a image?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97-7rWfQd5E

Comment: Generally speaking you might not want to zoom images with browsers, since the image interpolation algorithm provided used by browsers, to put it mildly, suck. Also, the effect is called the [Ken Burns Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Burns_Effect), for future references.

Comment: thx. Actually I was thinking to add this effect into the mobile device (iPhone and so on). But scare performance issue now :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case everyone need it, this is what I found... it's call Ken Burns Effect, thank to [Yi Jiang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313758/yi-jiang) who give me the name.

http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/

http://www.hashbangcode.com/examples/jquery-crossslide/ken-burns-fading.php

http://codecanyon.net/item/estro-jquery-ken-burns-swipe-effect-slider/235111?ref=jtop&clickthrough_id=23339470&redirect_back=true

Answer (score 0):

I think [ClearBox](http://www.clearbox.hu/index_en.html) is quite similar.

Comment: the slider is yes, but not the zoom. What I mean is like when the image show, the image itself is slowly zoom from far to near, but the container remain unchange. Is it possible to done on the JavaScript or must use flash?

Comment: The slide no problem, just it dun have the animation/transition for the image (zoom from far to near)...

Answer (score 0):

Ken Burns effect.. I recommend [Estro Slider](http://pixelentity.com/previews/components/estro/). It has great features, but it's not free plugin..
Also have a look at this list.. You may get some great options there.

http://libjunkie.com/javascript/gallery-slideshow-carousel